# python3 string "abcd" print: aababcabcd?

Tags: python, string

If a have a string like `abcd` or `1234` etc. how can I print together, the first character, then the first two characters, then the first three etc. all together?

For example for a `string = 1234` I would like to print/return `1121231234` or `aababcabcd`

I have this code so far:

```
def string_splosion(str):
    i = 0
    while i <= len(str):
        i += 1
        print(str[:i])
print(string_splosion('abcd'))
```

But it prints/returns it in separate lines. I could write it manually as `print(str[0:1], str[1:2] <...>)` but how do I make python do it as I don't know how long the string is going to be?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You shouldn't use `str` as a variable name, because it shadows the [built-in `str` type](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=join#text-sequence-type-str). You could join the sliced strings together in your loop:

```
def string_splosion(string):
    i, result = 0, ''
    while i < len(string): # < instead of <=
        i += 1
        result += string[:i]
    return result
```

It's possible to shorten your code a little using [`str.join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=join#str.join) and [`range`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=range#range):

```
def string_splosion(string):
    return ''.join(string[:i] for i in range(1, len(string) + 1))
```

or using [`itertools.accumulate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.accumulate) (Python 3.2+):

```
import itertools
def string_splosion(string):
    return ''.join(itertools.accumulate(string))
```

`itertools.accumulate` approach appears to be 2 times faster than `str.join` one and about 1.5 times faster than the original loop-based solution:

```
string_splosion_loop(abcdef): 2.3944241080715223
string_splosion_join_gen(abcdef): 2.757582983268288
string_splosion_join_lc(abcdef): 2.2879220573578865
string_splosion_itertools(abcdef): 1.1873638161591886
```

---

The code I used to time the functions is

```
import itertools
from timeit import timeit

string = 'abcdef'

def string_splosion_loop():
    i, result = 0, ''
    while i < len(string):
        i += 1
        result += string[:i]
    return result

def string_splosion_join_gen():
    return ''.join(string[:i] for i in range(1, len(string) + 1))

def string_splosion_join_lc():
    # str.join performs faster when the argument is a list
    return ''.join([string[:i] for i in range(1, len(string) + 1)])

def string_splosion_itertools():
    return ''.join(itertools.accumulate(string))

funcs = (string_splosion_loop, string_splosion_join_gen, 
         string_splosion_join_lc, string_splosion_itertools)

for f in funcs:
    print('{.__name__}({}): {}'.format(f, string, timeit(f)))
```

Comment: You are right about the string name, but that's what is used in the exercises. I usually change it to x or something when working on it and then change it back ( working at codingbat).
your second line: i, result = o, ''  I'm assuming the '' the same( i is 0, ''(the same)

Comment: It is possible (maybe it's also worthless...) to strip a cycle in the list comprehension (proposed solution no.2) using `range(1,len(string)+1)`.

Comment: @AL12 I'm not quite sure I understand, sorry. `i, result = 1, ''` assigns the empty string to the `result` variable and integer value 1 to `i` variable. This is called *sequence unpacking assignment*.

Answer (score 4):

Just use:

```
"".join([s[:i] for i in range(len(s)+1)])
```

As @abc noted, don't use `str` as a variable name because it's one of the default type. see https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#sequence-types-str-unicode-list-tuple-bytearray-buffer-xrange

E.g.:

```
>>> s = "1234"
>>> "".join([s[:i] for i in range(len(s)+1)])
'1121231234'
>>> s = "abcd"
>>> "".join([s[:i] for i in range(len(s)+1)])
'aababcabcd'
```

---

`range(len(s)+1)` is because of slicing, see [Explain Python's slice notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/explain-pythons-slice-notation):

```
>>> s = "1234"
>>> len(s)
4
>>> range(len(s))
[0, 1, 2, 3]
>>> s[:3]
'123'
>>> range(len(s)+1)
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> s[:4]
'1234'
```

Then:

```
>>> s[:0]
''
>>> s[:1]
'1'
>>> s[:2]
'12'
>>> s[:3]
'123'
>>> s[:4]
'1234'
```

Lastly, join `list([s[:1], s[:2], s[:3], s[:4]])` using `"".join(list)`, see https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.join:

```
>>> list([s[:1], s[:2], s[:3], s[:4]])
['1', '12', '123', '1234']
>>> x = list([s[:1], s[:2], s[:3], s[:4]])
>>> "".join(x)
'1121231234'
>>> "-".join(x)
'1-12-123-1234'
>>> " ".join(x)
'1 12 123 1234'
```

To avoid extract iteration in loop, you can use `range(1,len(s)+1)` since `s[:0]` returns string of 0 length:

```
>>> s = "1234"
>>> "".join([s[:i] for i in range(1,len(s)+1)])
'1121231234'
>>> "".join([s[:i] for i in range(len(s)+1)])
'1121231234'
```

Comment: in your code: "".join([s[:i] for i in range(len(s)+1)])
what does the "" at the beginning do?

Comment: updated the answer, hope the examples on `str.join()` helps, IMHO, you should also go and take a look at the documentations when the answer goes "see ..."

Answer (score 0):

If you are using python 3 you can use this to print without a newline:

```
print(yourString, end="")
```

So your function could be:

```
def string_splosion(str):
    for i in range(len(str)):
        print(str[:i], end="")
print(string_splosion('abcd'))
```